# How to load and build react app under a scoped object using vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite, global-object

I am using react and vite and noticing react is adding properties in global object since I will serve my react app as a third party I don't want it to pollute the global object meaning to load the properties in a different object like Window.MY_APP to load the required properties.

Webpack has a support for this using globalObject.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject

how can I achieve the same in vite.

Comment: "*react is adding properties in global object*" - is it? Which ones?

Comment: $RefreshReg$
$RefreshSig$
__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ and others.